# New top bar UI has serious deficiencies

Tags: feature-request, chat, meta, top-bar

The new UI that just appeared at the top has several serious deficiencies.

The most important are is that the links to [meta] and [chat] are gone.   It is now almost impossible for new users to discover these features.  Similarly, the link from meta to quickly navigate back to [main] is gone.

I strongly urge that these links be restored to the bar.

I also think the high tech styling at the top of the SA more traditional skin is very disconcerting, but that is only an aesthetic issue.

Comment: Also, try finding Seasoned Advice in the "Find a Stack Exchange site" search if you don't know what it's called. On the bright side, the blog is now a bit easier to find.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Please report that search issue separately! Tacking one more thing onto a more subjective existing list isn't a good way to report an actual bug.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree about meta: help > "discuss the workings and policies of this site" is a lot more discoverable for new users than "meta" (what is that?!). Yes, it takes one more click, but I think you're drastically overreacting based on how you're used to getting to it.

On the other hand, chat is indeed less discoverable, unless the RHS ad for it is showing up. (I'm not sure how often it does - [asked here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210051/when-is-the-rhs-chat-box-shown).) A new user, finding a forum-like site, is really not going to expect that the StackExchange (what does that even mean?) menu contains a link to a parallel site for unstructured chat!